# How to Illustrate Results from Cox model with Covariates

Tags: data-visualization, survival, cox-model

I have a data set for which I have fit a Cox proportional hazards model. For publication, I'd like to plot a graphical representation (perhaps a cumulative incidence) curve. My variable of interest is continuous but for illustration I can median-split and show the striking difference in incidence among the two groups (after adjustment for covariates). How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an adjustment for covariates is needed to illustrate the relationship of your continuous variable of interest to outcome fairly, then you should consider displaying 2 predicted survival curves that differ only in terms of that variable of interest.

For the predicted curves, choose representative values of the other covariates (same set of covariate values for both curves) with one predicted curve for, say, the 20th and one for the 80th percentile of that continuous variable of interest. (This, of course, assumes that the covariates don't differ very wildly as a function of that continuous variable so that you can have a representative set of shared covariate values.) Be sure to specify in the legend to your figure the set of covariate values used, and display confidence intervals for the predicted curves.

The way to generate such predicted curves depends on the software that you use. If you are going to do a lot of regression work (whether ordinary, logistic, ordinal, or Cox), it could be worth the learning curve to use the [`rms` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rms) in R, which provides a large set of useful tools for developing, validating, calibrating, and displaying regression models.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that survival curves are perhaps frowned upon as they can be misleading at times but this is needed for presentation to a physician audience who might be better off remembering pictures and not numbers.

Comment: Which function is most useful to achieve a "cumulative survival" plot after I have fit my Cox model?

Comment: @mindhabits any survival plotting function that can handle predictions from a Cox model will do. In base R, you can use `survfit.coxph()` to get survivor functions with confidence intervals for any set of covariates specified in `newdata`, then `plot.survfit()` to display. I prefer `survplot()` in the `rms` package, but you must be careful to set up the initial `cph` Cox model object in the way that the package expects: calculate a `datadist` from the data set, set the `datadist` option to that, and set `x`,`y`, and `surv` to TRUE along with a useful `time.inc` value in the call to `cph()`.